# Configure a layer in GeoServer so it is displayed with a transparent background?

Tags: geoserver, transparency-opacity

I use GeoServer to serve shapefile data as layers, and a program called 'Sitmun' to display them. Sitmun allows for the superposition of several layers. But, since my GeoServer seems to be delivering the layers with an opaque background, superposition is not working as desired. Layers taken from a governmental service – which I do not manage – have got a transparent background and work just fine.

How can I configure my GeoServer to serve layers with transparent backgrounds?

Comment: how are you requesting the layers? did you include transparent=true in the request? the question you link to is irrelevant as it is about a raster layer.

Comment: And what format do you request? JPEG cannot be made stansparent.

Comment: @IanTurton. 'Sitmun' does the request for me. I'm affraid it doesn't let me configure parameters. But layers from «IDEIB» (governmental SDI) are rendered with a transparent background, with no need of a parameter, apparently.

Comment: @user30184. I'm essentially blind to the final request. 'Sitmun' sends it for me, without actually showing it.

Comment: You can see from the GeoServer logs what it is sending.

Comment: @user30184. It's requesting jpeg.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GeoServer serves the images it is asked for. The trick to transparency is to use the `TRANSPARENT=TRUE` keyword in the request. You must also make sure you are requesting a format that supports transparency such as png or gif.

Comment: actually @nmtoken either case is fine

Comment: Perhaps in GeoServer, which is lax with regards the WMS standards, but the WMS standard tells us that parameter values are case sensitive and the allowable values for the TRAnsparenT parameter are TRUE | FALSE.

Comment: For anyone else using 'Sitmun' out there, the 'TRANSPARENT' parameter is handled in in the 'Service' panel. I was looking for it in the 'Cartography' panel, to no avail.