# Make raster background transparent

Tags: raster, geoserver, transparency-opacity

I am rendering mosaic using Geoserver imageMosaic plugin. I have already about 4000 VRT-s with overviews processed and I am using Geoserver GDAL plugin to enable mosaic rendering with VRT-s as source. VRT-s consists of 12 bands but for rendering only RGB ones are needed in this case (achived that using SLD). Geotiff-s from which VRT-s are created are Uint16 and have no nodata defined and no alpha band, so when mosaic appears on screen black background is rendered where pixel values are equal to `0.0`. I have footprint shp file generated for every of my VRT-s and I tried to cut black part of image using it. It worked when format of rendering is set to image/jpeg, but image/png or any other format results in error (I found that is somehow  connected with Uint16 type of data), so I gave up on that solution. I also tried to style layer with different SLD solutions, but unfortunately without any success. I can make it work with few reprocessing steps but want to avoid that. Is there any solution regarding SLD file that will visualize my raster without black background. Here is my SLD, does anyone know how to extend it properly , or is it even possible to achieve without reprocessing my date into BYTE?

**SLD**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sld:StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" 
xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" 
xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" version="1.0.0">
<sld:NamedLayer>
<sld:Name></sld:Name>
<sld:LayerFeatureConstraints>
  <sld:FeatureTypeConstraint/>
</sld:LayerFeatureConstraints>
<sld:UserStyle>
  <sld:Title/>
  <sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
    <sld:Name>name</sld:Name>
    <sld:FeatureTypeName>Feature</sld:FeatureTypeName>
    <sld:Rule>
      <sld:RasterSymbolizer>
        <sld:Geometry>
          <ogc:PropertyName>grid</ogc:PropertyName>
        </sld:Geometry>
        <Opacity>
            1
        </Opacity>
        <ChannelSelection>
          <RedChannel>
            <SourceChannelName>3</SourceChannelName>
            <ContrastEnhancement>
              <Normalize>
                <VendorOption name="algorithm">StretchToMinimumMaximum</VendorOption>
                <VendorOption name="minValue">0</VendorOption>
                <VendorOption name="maxValue">12000</VendorOption>
              </Normalize>
              <GammaValue>0.45</GammaValue>
            </ContrastEnhancement>
          </RedChannel>
          <GreenChannel>
            <SourceChannelName>2</SourceChannelName>
            <ContrastEnhancement>
              <Normalize>
                <VendorOption name="algorithm">StretchToMinimumMaximum</VendorOption>
                <VendorOption name="minValue">0</VendorOption>
                <VendorOption name="maxValue">12000</VendorOption>
              </Normalize>
              <GammaValue>0.45</GammaValue>
            </ContrastEnhancement>
          </GreenChannel>
          <BlueChannel>
            <SourceChannelName>1</SourceChannelName>
            <ContrastEnhancement>
              <Normalize>
                <VendorOption name="algorithm">StretchToMinimumMaximum</VendorOption>
                <VendorOption name="minValue">0</VendorOption>
                <VendorOption name="maxValue">12000</VendorOption>
              </Normalize>
              <GammaValue>0.45</GammaValue>
            </ContrastEnhancement>
          </BlueChannel>
        </ChannelSelection>
        
      </sld:RasterSymbolizer>
    </sld:Rule>
  </sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
  </sld:UserStyle>
  </sld:NamedLayer>
  </sld:StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Example of request:

`http://192.168.180.132:9092/geoserver/test/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=test%3AT33TXJ_20190813T094031&bbox=478243.55712465756%2C4788975.3669867385%2C590025.6521432535%2C4900757.462005334&width=768&height=767&srs=EPSG%3A3765&styles=&format=image/png&TRANSPARENT=TRUE`

Comment: does https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/372050/configure-a-layer-in-geoserver-so-it-is-displayed-with-a-transparent-background answer your question?

Comment: Unfortunately no.

Comment: so you aren't requesting a JPEG? and you have set TRANSPARENT=TRUE in the request? - can you [edit] in the request you are sending

Comment: I updated the question with request example

Comment: If the GeoServer is recent enough, you can add the ``NoData=0`` in the mosaic property file (then reload the mosaic config and try again).

Comment: Using Geoserver 2.22 . I added NoData=0 / NoData=0.0 to indexer.properties and recreated mosaic, but still the same values are black on display. Should nodata be defined on raster already for this property to work properly ?